php recording the error session but it doesn't work
I'm learning PHP on YouTube and I met an issue I don't know what happened.
I'm creating a signup page and want to show the error message but the error session seems to be recorded. It stops in the signUp.inc.php as below.
signUp.inc.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $userName = $_POST["userName"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    try {
        require_once "dbh.inc.php";
        require_once "signUp_model.inc.php";
        require_once "signUp_contr.inc.php";

        // ERROR HANDLERS
        $errors = [];

        if (is_input_empty($userName, $pwd, $email)) {
            $errors["empty_input"] = "Fill in all fields";
        }
        if (is_email_invaild($email)) {
            $errors["invalid_email"] = "Invalid email used";
        }
        if (is_username_taken($pdo, $userName)) {
            $errors["username_taken"] = "Username already taken";
        }
        if (is_email_taken($pdo, $email)) {
            $errors["email_used"] = "Email already registered";
        }

        require_once "config_session.inc.php";

        if ($errors) {
            $_SESSION["errors_signUp"] = $errors;
            header("Location: ../index.php");
            exit();
        }
        
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit("Query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit("Query failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}

I think the config_session.inc.php and the signUp_view.inc.php are working but they can't get the message in the $_SESSION["errors_signUp"] from signUp.inc.php so they show NULL in the index.php.
I only found this reason but couldn't further find out why it happened and the solution. Could someone kindly tell me how to fix it, please?
config_session.inc.php
<?php

ini_set('session.use_only_cookie', 1); // https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1); 

session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 3600,
    'domain' => 'localhost',
    'path' => '/',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true
]); 

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['last_regeneration'])) {
    regenerate_session_id();
} else {
    $interval = 60 * 60;
    if(time() - $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] >= $interval) {
        regenerate_session_id();
    }
}

function regenerate_session_id() {
    session_regenerate_id(); //not sure it should be true
    $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] = time();
}

signup_view.inc.php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

function check_signUp_errors() 
{
    if(isset($_SESSION["errors_signUp"])){
        $errors = $_SESSION["errors_signUp"];

        echo "<br>";

        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo '<p class="form-error">' . $error . '</p>';
        }

        unset($_SESSION["errors_signUp"]);
    } 
}

index.php
<?php
require_once './includes/signUp_view.inc.php';
require_once './includes/config_session.inc.php';
// require_once './includes/signUp.inc.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hant">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./style/main.css' />
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h3>Login</h3>

   <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
      <button>Login</button>
   </form>

   <h3>Signup</h3>

   <form action="includes/signUp.inc.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
      <button>Signup</button>
   </form>

   

   <?php
   check_signUp_errors();
   ?>


</body>
</html> 

Many thanks <(_ _)>
I removed header("Location: ../index.php") in the signUp.inc.php and echo var_dump($_SESSION["errors_signUp"]); then I can see the messages in the $_SESSION["errors_signUp"].
However I used <?php echo var_dump($_SESSION) ?> in the index.php, which shows NULL.
I tried to use session_start(); to replace require_once "config_session.inc.php"; in the signUp.php but it didn't work.

Does the signUp_view.inc.php file print anything? Remember, you must start the session at the beginning of your code, nothing should be sent (not even whitespaces) as this will send the headers before the session starts.

Hi @WilliamCarneiro, thanks for the comment. signUp_view.inc.php is a file that saves the functions to provide index.php and shows any messages if the user fills in the wrong information on the page so it doesn't print anything by itself.
session_start() was wroten in the config_session.inc.php and require_once "config_session.inc.php" in the signUp.inc.php.

I see... Maybe there's a configuration error on your server (like a unwritable directory session.save_path in php.ini). Try looking at the server logs for more information.

Are there any clues (warnings, notices, etc) in your error logs? Have you checked if your files contain BOM characters? In your original setup of signUp.inc.php, you're filling the $_SESSION array, but the session is started in config_session.inc.php, which is included after your signup file. And if this is the tutorial you're following, you'll see that the author is including the files in the correct order.

Hi @FiddlingAway, thanks for the comment. I didn't see any clues in my error logs. Yes, I'm following the tutorial you mentioned.  config_session.inc.php should be in front of filling the $_SESSION in the signUp.inc.php , right? But it doesn't work.... I also re-wrote the code as the tutorial but it's the same....

@WilliamCarneiro I think you are right. I found I cannot use
'domain' => 'localhost, in the session_set_cookie_params. Maybe it's because I use Mac. After I changed to 'domain' => '127.0.0.1', the issue has been resolved.
Thank you.
And thank you too @FiddlingAway

Which address did you open in your browser?

@Randommm it was http://127.0.0.1/ but I used localhost in my coding.

In the config_session.inc.php
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 3600,
    'domain' => 'localhost',
    'path' => '/',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true
]);

change the domain to '127.0.0.1'
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 3600,
    'domain' => '127.0.0.1',
    'path' => '/',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true
]); 


How would this solve the issue?

@DarkBee cause OP didn't use the same"domain" they had open in the browser

Then Craig should add this to the answer. Code-only answers are not good answers
